# Mindstorms EV3 3D building instructions no longer working in Chrome

Tags: ev3, instructions

[Lego Mindstorms EV3 building instructions in 3D](http://www.us.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/community/bi) (so that one can rotate the model around and stuff) are available. This used to work fine on my machine in Google Chrome. However, I can no longer get it to work; when I click on any of the [links](http://www.us.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/community/bi/show?model=EV3RSTORM&mission=01), it says "Looks like our 3D view does not work in your browser. Try to use a different browser or download the PDF instead.". I followed instructions to [make sure webgl is enabled](https://superuser.com/a/836833/318722) in my browser, and I also [verified that webgl indeed does work](https://get.webgl.org/). What do I need to do to get the Lego Mindstorms EV3 building instructions in 3D to work in Chrome (version 45.0.2454.85 m)?

Comment: Have you tried contacting LEGO support? They might be interested in this issue, seeing that they explicitly state their site supports Chrome. Is installing / using another browser out of question? I have just tried using the latest Firefox and it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google deprecated support for NPAPI in April this year, and [removed it completely this month in Chrome 45](https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation).

LEGO has historically used Unity Web Player for a number of their online 3D games which has certainly been impacted by this change, and while this is not specifically the case here (the building instructions are "Powered by Autodesk Technology", possibly a variant of A360), it's probable that the underlying cause is the same - the plugin uses the older technology that Google is removing.

They do still work in Firefox if that helps.

Comment: A note on the lego page says "The web-based MINDSTORMS 3D Building Instructions are not supported by all browsers, as it uses WebGL Technology". I have confirmed by going to https://get.webgl.org/ that webgl still works in Chrome 45. I guess the note is inaccurate.

Comment: Yes, it's about 10 versions out, mentioning Chrome 35 I believe. Agree the Chrome itself supports WebGL, but I guess there's some other logic they are testing for that isn't working.